# Transfer data from specific sheet of multiple files to master file

Tags: excel, vba

Can someone help me on the following:
I have about 12 workbooks in the folder "Fiscal Year 11-12". All the 12 files have a common sheet by the name "Categorized". I'm trying to transfer data from that sheet of all the files to a file YearlyExpense.xlsm, but I get the following error:

> run-time error 1004. *"xxx.xlsx" could not be found. Check the
>   spelling of  the name, and verify that the file location is correct.*

My code is as follows:

```
Sub LoopThroughDirectory()

Dim MyFile As String
Dim erow
MyFile = Dir("C:\Users\Winston\Documents\Family Budget\Fiscal Year 11-12\")

Do While Len(MyFile) > 0
    If MyFile = "YearlyExpense.Xlsm" Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Workbooks.Open (MyFile) 
      'This is where I'm getting error 1004 vba

    Sheets("Categorized").Select
    Range("B32:V32").Copy
    ActiveWorkbook.Close

    erow = Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
    ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("sheet2").Range(Cells(erow, 1), Cells(erow, 22))

    MyFile = Dir
Loop
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

You need to express the full path *and* directory listing file mask on the initial call to `Dir`. This will only return the filename; you need to concatenate it with the path to the folder that the file resides in. After processing the first file, you need to call `Dir` again to get the next file in that folder that complies with the original file mask.

```
Sub LoopThroughDirectory()

    Dim myFile As String, myPath As String, wb As Workbook

    myPath = "C:\Users\Winston\Documents\Family Budget\Fiscal Year 11-12\"
    myFile = Dir(myPath & "\*.xl*")

    Do While Len(myFile) > 0
        If LCase(myFile) <> "yearlyexpense.xlsm" Then

            Debug.Print myPath & Chr(92) & myFile  'use THIS to open the workbook
            Set wb = Workbooks.Open(myPath & Chr(92) & myFile)
            With wb.Sheets("Categorized")
                'I'll admit to some confusion here as to what gets copied and to where
                .Range("B32:V32").Copy _
                    Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            End With
            wb.Close False
            Set wb = Nothing
        End If
        myFile = Dir
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi there, as mentioned earlier, I have 12 excel files in the path specified. Now, the objective is to copy a row ranging from B32:V32 in each file to the destination file "yearlyexpense.xlsm" in the next available empty row.